# I get a sigabort when it tries to run isKindofClass

Tags: cocoa

```
void PrintIntrospectionInfo()
{
// NSLog(@"Comes here1");

NSArray *myArray;
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
NSValue *aValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSURL *urlObj = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
NSString *aString = @"string";
NSMutableString *mString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"Hello, %@", aString];
NSDictionary *stanford = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://www.stanford.edu", @"Stanford University", @"http://www.apple.com",@"Apple", @"http://cs193p.stanford.edu", @"CS193P",@"http://itunes.stanford.edu",@"Stanford on iTunesU",@"http://stanfordshop.com",@"Stanford Mall", nil];

myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aDate, aValue, aString,stanford,urlObj,mString, nil];

for(id someObject in myArray)
{
    NSLog(@"Comes here");

    if([someObject isKindofClass:[NSString string]])
    {

    }
}


}
```

Comment: you should pass a class, not a string: `[someObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]`

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
for(id someObject in myArray)
{
    NSLog(@"Comes here");
    if([someObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {

    }
}
```

instead. Note that `Of` of `isKindOfClass` is in the upper case. I recommend you to use `NSObject*` instead of `id`. Then the compiler warns you that the method `isKindofClass` is not available. Usually, you don't need to use `id` unless you use something which is not an `NSObject` :

```
for(NSObject* someObject in myArray)
```

Comment: Also, you're actually passing a class, where the questioner was passing a string instance. That's what fixes the crash.